# facebook app request: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frictionless_value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a very simple code in javascript/jquery to allow a user to send a facebook app request to other friends. It works just fine if the user sends any requests, but fails miserably if the user closes the window without sending anything. The error message is posted in the title. **It did not happen before**.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: msg, title: title, data: from_data}, function (response) {
    if (response && response.request_ids) {
    $.post("games", {action:"sentRequests", requestIds:JSON.stringify(response.request_ids)}, function () {
            //store the app requests in the server.
        });
    } else {
        alert ("Requests cancelled.");
    }
});
```

The alert never happens, so I believe it's the way I'm handling the undefined response. Any ideas?

PS: replacing the condition for `if (response !== undefined)` does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a bug in the facebook api. Nothing related to jquery :/

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16200

Answer (score 0):

Try using firebug to add a break point and debug the code. View the variables contents to verify it's getting in to each line and work from there

Comment: It does not really tell me much, tho... line 25 of all.js (facebook script): `FB.provide('Frictionless',{_allowedRecipients:{},_updateRecipients:function(){FB.Frictionless._allowedRecipients={};` etc etc (too long a line for a comment)

Comment: Actually, it says also `c is undefined`